# Animation on image view on grid view

Tags: android, animation

I have a grid view with 2 columns and each item in grid view having one image and 2 textview below the image.

I have added one button over each image and after clicking on button I want that image should scale and move down to bottom tab.

Like it should appear image drop down from its position in side one button of tabview.

I am able to add animation on image using this code

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation trAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 160,0, 100);
trAnimation.setDuration(500);
set.addAnimation(trAnimation);

Animation scaleAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_scale);

set.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
set.setFillEnabled(true) ;
set.setFillAfter(true);

view.setAlpha(100) ;
view.startAnimation(set);
```

But problem is that image is not coming to bottom of screen it is going inside of grid item where it is placed . anybody knows how to move this image to bottom.